# Can I create rotated (skewed) guides/grid in scribus?

Tags: inkscape, scribus

I would like to use skewed guides in scribus, reproducing a layout of tiles where "verticals" are about 80 degrees to the horizontal line. I don't see this option in scribus, am I overlooking something? Inkscape offers that possibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no such guides in Scribus.

The feature has been discussed in the past, but other features were (and probably are) considered as more urgent (afaict, they are more relevant to vector graphics than layouting...).

Depending on what you are trying to achieve you can go back and forth from Inkscape; create there the skeleton for your document and fill it in Scribus.
As a reminder: you can "copy" (or load) a group of skewed rectangles from Inkscape and convert them to image or text frames in Scribus.

If you want to stay inside of Scribus, you can also:

- create a shape (rectangle)
- convert it to a polygon
- draw a line and turn it to 80°
- you can use the "width" from the properties palette to make it longer without changing its rotation)
- convert the line to a bezier curve (a path)
- eventually make multiple copies of the lines
- select the line (... the path...) and the shape...
- ... and use "item > path tools > cut polygon" to create a skewed rectangle that matches your needs.
- convert the polygon to a text or image frame.

Sounds very complex, but -- while not as simple as a guide -- it can be better than nothing...